# After spill, half of laptop screen is negative

Tags: display, keyboard, lcd

About a week ago I spilled a small amount of orange juice on the bottom right portion of my Dell laptop screen, and upper right portion of the keyboard.

The screen went through a few different phases of functionality including being half black and half gray, being covered in yellow vertical lines. After 4 days the left side of my screen is now working properly, while the right side is displaying everything in negative (color inversion).

Does anyone have thoughts on what the problem is and the best way to fix it?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop. You drowned it. Electronics don't like conductive, let alone sticky, liquids.

Comment: It probably needs to be disassembled and washed.  With luck, nothing has been permanently damaged, but the acid juice will tend to corrode stuff, and the longer you wait the worse it gets.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have thoughts on what the problem is

Easy. The problem is that orange juice was spilled on the laptop.

This is bad. It is acidic, contains sugar (which will not evaporate and will continue to atract moisture) and it will create short ciruits.

> and the best way to fix it?

At the moment of the spill power down the laptop as fast as possible. Pull the battery and main power if you need to. **Under no circumstances re-apply power until the spill it fixed**.

Take apart the laptop and carefully remove as much spille juice as possible. Rince thoroughly with demineralised water or cleaning alcohol. Then let it dry for a week. Do not attempt to turn it back on until it is completely dry. If needed assist with a hair dryer on a cold setting.

So much on what should have happened.

In you case you did not power it down soon enough or powered it back up while there was still moisture left. That can either short items and destroy them permanently, or just lead to shorts until dry or in moist weather.

**You really want to clean this out** and pray nothing broke permanently yet. Best solution: take it to a repair shop and ask for a quote. With luck it might only need cleaning. If you do not have much luck on or the invertors or other screen part might already be dammaged. In which case you are looking at a screen or a laptop replacement.